# Выделить всё между символами (regex) не включая эти символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```html
{0}{5}
{1}{dfdf}
{2}{пара, пара п.а пара&па®}
{3}{dfdf!}
```

regex {([\s\S]+?)} выделяет вместе с фигурными скобками, как исключить скобки оставив только содержание?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, можно сделать так

```
 [^\{\}]
```

Результат http://regexr.com/3eonp. Меня пугает сложность некоторых ответов, я чего-то не понимаю в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать прямой `(?=)` и обратный `(?<=)` просмотр

```
(?<=\{)([\s\S]+?)(?=\})
```

Можно посмотреть [тут](https://regex101.com/r/PxbTYd/1)

Другой вариант - брать только группу которая в скобках. Если выражение используется для поиска и замены, можно заменять на `{$1}`

Answer (score 0):

Просто брать из результата первую группу:

```js
var res = [];

`{0}{5}
{1}{dfdf}
{2}{пара, пара п.а пара&па®}
{3}{dfdf!}`.replace(/\{([\s\S]*?)\}/g, (m, g) => { res.push(g) });

console.log(res);
```